# Shared variable accross Laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, session, middleware

First all, I'm pretty new in Laravel, so I'm trying to figure out my way around it.

I'm now running into a problem (that I'm probably not trying to fix the correct way, so any input will be appreciated!) that I can't seem to solve.

At some point in the workflow, the user should be able to set a variable. What I'm trying to do is to redirect the user in case this variable hasn't been set, and this for (almost) every page. 
When the user set this variable, I'm able to save it in the session, and then fetch it from pretty much everywhere. This is done in a controller.

For the redirect part, I had the idea of using a middleware looking for the variable, and redirect to the correct page if not present.
My problem is that I can't seem to fetch it from the middleware.

I'm using the `Route::group(['$middlewareGroups' => ['web']], function () {` thingy in order to have the session started when getting into the middleware. I even tried  `\Session::start()` manually. And if I manage to have a session starting, it's empty. Somehow, when it gets out of the middleware to the controller, the values are correctly set (but it's too late for me as I want to redirect from the middleware).

Any idea on how to proceed ? What would be the best way to solve this problems ?

Thanks!

Comment: Wait, are you starting a session in the `Route::group`? Either way, Laravel uses it's own session handler, it doesn't use the default sessions that PHP provides. With that said, normally a session is started when a user logs in(by what means, that's for you to decide).

Comment: As I read on a few blog posts, I'm using the group thing in order to have  `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class` (as defined in the kernel) set. I also tried to move this line to the `$middleware` variable in the same file, with the same result. I'm probably not using the exact terms though. I don't have a proper login (yet), but do you think that would be the way to go ? (I mean set the variable from there and then use the Authenticate middleware (I guess)). Thanks for the help anyway

Comment: Well, thankfully laravel ships out of the box with a proper auth [see here](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/the-auth-scaffold-in-laravel-5-2). Long story short, do `php artisan make:auth`. Now to the next issue: let's take it from the top. What exactly are you trying to achieve, maybe there's another way to do this that doesn't involve so much hassle.

Comment: You know what, [let's move this to chat, it's easier](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124553/laravel-site-wide-var)

Comment: Hey @andrew, I managed to have everything working using the Auth middleware. Thanks a lot again for your time and help!

Comment: No worries mate, glad to help.